# Where do I put my Spring Boot REST API jar file on my Ubuntu EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, sftp

I have an Ubuntu EC2 instance on which I want to place a Spring Boot REST API jar file, which I've built on my computer. I'm going to use Filezilla to transfer the jar file over SFTP to my Ubuntu EC2 instance. Does it need to go into a certain directory if I want to use that EC2 instance for sending HTTP request to the REST API?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you mean ? Doesn't matter where you keep it ? you can create any directory and keep it . You need to specify the port while starting your jar and access the REST endpoint from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to send request to REST API from Spring Boot application which is included in Ubuntu EC2 instance. You don't need to put spring boot application in a specific directory. Make sure that you've installed java in EC2 instance. You just have to run spring boot application and open port `8080` (for embedded tomcat server) from the security group. Most importantly you've to check whether EC2 instance was launched in public subnet.